# Error de consumo api en flutter

Tags: json, flutter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas noches estimados. Soy nuevo en flutter, quiero listar los nombres de la lista de routegroups. Alguien que le halla pasado algo parecido.

> Error:The method '[]' was called on null.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: estás tratando de acceder al elemento 1 directamente, te aseguraste de que todos los elementos tengan al menos algún elemento dentro de `routegroups`? si es así, entonces prueba con  item[0], o valida primero:  if(item.isNotEmpty) { print(item[0]['name'])

Comment: Como recomendación, la próxima vez, no pongas imágenes, pon el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema lo genera lo que tienes en

```
print(item[1]["name"])
```

debería de ser solo

```
print(item["name"])
```

ya que item ya es un Map.

También te recomiendo utilizar clases y constructores con el json para que sea mas sencillo saber los errores saludos.

Answer (score 0):

si quieres listar te recomiendo que uses un `ListView.builder` de esta manera tu podrás obtener el índice de la cade uno de los elementos de tu lista y los podrás mostrar sin ningún problema, tal que así:

```
    ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: listaItems!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (itemBuilder, index) {
                   return Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 
                      5),
                      height: 60,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Card(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 
                             15),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: const Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                              trailing: const 
                              Icon(Icons.arrow_right_sharp),
                              title: Text(
                                listaItems[index].nombre!,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, 
                                fontSize: 17),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
```

el `listaItems` yo lo obtengo desde un `FutureBuilder`, una vez que lo obtengo, valido que haya datos en el método `Future`, asigno el `snapshot.data` a la variable `listaItems` y luego retorno el `ListView.Builder`.

Comment: gracias , estimados logre listar en un ListView.builder , intentare realizar lo mismo con el FutureBuilder.